# How to prove the following $\Theta$notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If the following function is given: $f(n)=n^2+ n \ln(n)+1$. 
How do  you prove the $\Theta$ notation?

I assume that is must be $\Theta$($n^2$). 
But I'm not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that

$$n^2\le f(n),\quad \forall n\ge1$$
so
$$n^2=\mathcal O(f(n))$$
moreover we have

$$\ln n\le n,\quad \forall n\ge1$$
so
$$f(n)\le 3n^2 ,\quad \forall n\ge1$$
and then
$$f(n)=\mathcal O(n^2)$$
so we get
$$f(n)=\Theta(n^2)$$

Comment: Can you please explain this step(It's not clear how you get $3n^2$): $$\ln n\le n,\quad \forall n\ge1$$
so
$$f(n)\le 3n^2 ,\quad \forall n\ge1$$

Comment: Since $\ln n\le n$ so $n\ln n\le n^2$ and since $1\le n^2$ we get
$$f(n)=n^2+n\ln n+1\le 3n^2$$

Answer (score 1):

You may write, as $n$ tends to $+\infty$,
$$
\frac{f(n)}{n^2}=\frac{n^2+ n \ln n +1}{n^2}=1+\frac{\ln n}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}
$$
thus
$$
\frac{f(n)}{n^2} \rightarrow 1
$$ then $f(n)=\Theta(n^2)$ moreover $f(n)\sim_{+\infty}n^2.$